# Need example for securing normal Spring REST APIs with Keycloack and oAuth2

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-security, keycloak

I need to secure my spring REST APIs with access token obtain from Keycloak and validation done by Spring security adapter.

I have my mobile client which will be calling APIs from my server which needs to be validated with access token obtained from Keycloak

Comment: Provide your effort and post question where you having problem you can find tutorials on different site for what you want to achieve.

Comment: Actually I am quite new to Kecloack and Spring security. Thats why needed a start point

Comment: Well then did you google it?

Comment: Yes. I am stuck with the point how to use kecloak.json and how to obtain oAuth token and how to validate it through SPring security

Comment: That's what these people are talking about. Where are you stuck - how are you stuck - what have you done - what's your errors

Comment: https://dzone.com/articles/easily-secure-your-spring-boot-applications-with-k This will be helpful

Comment: This example redirects to keycloak login page. Which I dont want. I have mobile client and want to validate it through oAuth tokens. So my point is how to obtain oAuth token and validate it through Spring security

Comment: Then make a specific question about the mobile part, the spring security part is covered by my blogpost that Hiren linked in the comments.

Comment: Though kecloak.json file is present in src/main/resources it gving following exception    java.io.FileNotFoundException: Unable to locate Keycloak configuration file: keycloak.json

Comment: Finally got success! with SpringBoot Thanks all for your help

Answer (score 0):

You can find an example with what you need wright here:
https://github.com/iuliazidaru/keycloak-spring-boot-rest-angular-demo